# Error when creating debain source package with dpkg

Tags: dpkg, packaging, error-handling

When entering this `dpkg-source -b <packagename>` into the terminal to create a debian source package, I get the following error:

```
dpkg-source: error: syntax error in ResolutionX_1.0-0/debian/control at line 9:
first block lacks a source field
```

What does this mean?

My debian control file contains:

```
Package: ResolutionX
Version: 1.0-0
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
Maintainer: xx 
Description: ResolutionX
    A simple tool to enable you to have your desired resolution without requiring graphics drivers.
```

Comment: Well, what does `ResolutionX_1.0-0/debian/control` contain? At least the first 10 lines of it?

Comment: @muru see edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Package: ResolutionX
Version: 1.0-0
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
Maintainer: First_name Last_name 
Description: ResolutionX
    A simple tool to enable you to have your desired resolution without requiring graphics drivers.
```

This paragraph is a mish-mash of fields for source and binary packages.
The first paragraph should describe [the *source* package](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-sourcecontrolfiles). Here, that would mean the first line has `Source:` instead of `Package:`. You can only specify `Build-Depends` for source packages, and `Architecture` for binary packages. The `Version` is derived from `debian/changelog`, and is not specified in `debian/control`.

I don't know how the rest of `debian/control` looks like, but just from this, I think you should split up the first paragraph:

```
Source: resolutionx
Version: 1.0-0
Section: base
Priority: optional
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
Maintainer: First_name Last_name 

Package: resolutionx
Section: base
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Description: ResolutionX
 A simple tool to enable you to have your desired resolution
```

Also note that packages are not supposed to have capital letters in their name. Indeed, packages to submitted to the Debian or Ubuntu repositories *cannot* have capital letters in their names.

Comment: Also, the Maintainer field should be formatted as `First Last <email@address.com>`

Comment: @TellMeWhy FYI the name remains in the revision history. If you want it completely redacted, flag for a mod.