# What is wrong with this control file?

Tags: packaging

At first I was encountering the same error as [Error when creating debain source package with dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660261/error-when-creating-debain-source-package-with-dpkg).

After following its answer I am facing this problem

```
tata@archisman-HP-240-G3-Notebook-PC ~/brightness-controller $ debuild
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package PACKAGE
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 1.2
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution trusty
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Archisman Panigrahi <tata@archisman-HP-240-G3-Notebook-PC>
dpkg-source --before-build brightness-controller
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Version' in input data in general section of control info file
dpkg-source: warning: unknown information field 'Architecture' in input data in general section of control info file
dpkg-source: error: source package name 'PACKAGE' is illegal: character 'P' not allowed
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source --before-build brightness-controller gave error exit status 255
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

The control file is

```
Source: brightness-controller
Section: accessories
Priority: optional
Maintainer: Archisman Panigrahi <apandada1@gmail.com>
Version: 1.2
Architecture: all
Build-Depends: python-wxgtk2.8,
               python,
               xrandr,
Homepage: http://lordamit.github.io/Brightness

Package: brightness-controller
Architecture: any
Depends: python-wxgtk2.8,
         python,
         xrandr,
Description: Brightness Controller is the only GUI application for Linux that allows you to control brightness 
of your primary and secondary display from the same place. It is a software based dimmer.
Released under GPL-3, Brightness Controller's source code is available at
.
https://github.com/lordamit/Brightness
.
If you encounter any problem you can open an issue in the GitHub project. 
.
Kindly review and let your friends know if this application made your display more friendly to your eyes.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Debian Policy Manual, chapter [Control files and their fields](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html):

> The fields in the general paragraph (the first one, for the source
>   package) are:
>
> - Source (mandatory)
> - Maintainer (mandatory)
> - Uploaders
> - Section (recommended)
> - Priority (recommended)
> - Build-Depends et al
> - Standards-Version (recommended)
> - Homepage
> - Vcs-Browser, Vcs-Git, et al.
>
> The fields in the binary package paragraphs are:
>
> - Package (mandatory)
> - Architecture (mandatory)
> - Section (recommended)
> - Priority (recommended)
> - Essential
> - Depends et al
> - Description (mandatory)
> - Homepage
> - Built-Using
> - Package-Type

Clearly, neither `Version` nor `Architecture` belongs in the first paragraph (the source package one). `Version` doesn't belong in `debian/control` *at all*. The version is determined from `debian/changelog`, and only the final package's generated `DEBIAN/control` will contain `Version`.

Looks like some file in `debian`, probably `debian/changelog`, isn't properly created. It uses `PACKAGE` as the package name, where it should be `brightness-controller`. Package names are always lower-case.